# Black screen boot after installing CUDA 10.0 on versions 18.04.3 / 18.04 / 16.04.6

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda

I am trying to install CUDA 10.0 because tensorflow 1.13/1.14 only supports this version.

I have just installed a clean version of Ubuntu 18.04.3 (same issue occurs with 18.04 and 16.04.6) following [these instructions](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0), downloaded form [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop). I chose the minimal install option so Ubuntu doesn't install any drivers.

The first time I log in, I open a terminal and run the following

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
$ sudo apt install build-essential
$ sudo apt-get install manpages-dev
```

At this stage, there are no nvidia drivers and no cuda software installed (to make sure, I also `purge` nvidia and cuda).

I download CUDA 10.0 from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.0-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804&target_type=deblocal) and proceed to run it via (I am following the nvidia instructions [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/10.0/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#post-installation-actions))

```
$ sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu.x.deb
$ sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-10.0-local/7fa2af80.pub
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install cuda
$ export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
$ sudo reboot
```

When I reboot however, I get a black screen with the top line giving some information about my nvme internal drive partition

```
/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 185049/30498816 files, 5606916/121965056 blocks
```

I can't even use `CTRL+ALT+F2` here because it seems like the screen keeps jumping and doesn't allow me to type.

This only happens after installing cuda 10.0 specifically. If I try a separate run where I only install a nvidia driver **without** having installed cuda 10.0, I can reboot my computer multiple times and it works fine (this issue was suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162078#162078)). This is strange because the nvidia driver automatically installs cuda 10.1 (this issue is also mentioned at the end of [this post](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/building-tensorflow-1-14-with-gpu-support-and-tensorrt-on-ubuntu-16-04-84bbd356e03)) as displayed by the `nvidia-smi` command.

**How can I fix the black boot screen issue and still have cuda 10.0 installed?**

The GPU is a GeFroce RTX 2070 Super (list of supported nvidia drivers [here](https://www.geforce.co.uk/drivers))

Comment: Same problem with similar configuration: Ubuntu 20.04 + RTX3090 eGPU. Works with the proprietary Nvidia driver, until I install CUDA. Then it hangs on boot. Interestingly, when I disconnect NVidia from a laptop (it is working via Thunderbolt) it boots with ease.